# How to find a symbol for method

Tags: java

I'm trying to take the string that a user inputs and return the vowels in the string. The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
> VowelsA3.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
>            if (isVowel.isVowelValid(letter) = true)
>                       ^   symbol:   method isVowelValid(char)   location: class isVowel
```

Here's my code for "VowelsA3" (my main that will not compile):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class VowelsA3 
{
      public static void main (String[] args) 
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter a string.");
      String userInput = scan.nextLine();
      char letter = 'x';
      for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.length(); i++) 
      {
           letter = userInput.charAt(i);
           if (isVowel.isVowelValid(letter) = true)
          { 
            System.out.println(letter);
          }          
      }      
    }   
}
```

Here is my method "isVowel" that does compile:

```
public class isVowel 
{
    public static boolean isValidVowel(char letter)
    {
      boolean trueVowel = false;
      {
      if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i' || letter == 'o' || letter == 'u')
      {
          trueVowel = true;
      }
      else
      {
          trueVowel = false;  
      }
      return trueVowel;
      }
    }
 }
```

Any ideas? I've been told I was an idiot for using "== true" on the line where the error is because my method is returning a true/false anyway, but I thought I had to do this so that the if statement would work - without me asking whether the returned value is true I cannot know whether or not it is a vowel, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isVowel` is a class and `isValidVowel()` is a method inside this class. Therefore, you should call

```
isVowel.isValidVowel(letter).isValidVowel
```

instead of `isVowelValid`.

You should call `isVowel.isValidVowel(letter) == true.`

Actually because `isValidVowel(letter)` return `true/false`, you do not need to `check == true`. Just call

```
if (isVowel.isValidVowel(letter))
    System.out.println(letter);
```

Comment: It's normal to make mistake ^^! Just relax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CLASSNAME.STATIC_METHOD_NAME(PARAMETERS)

```
if (isVowel.isValidVowel(letter) == true)
```

instead of

```
if (isVowel(letter) == true)
```

So since you have isVowel as class name, so you cant use classname(parameter) instead you need to use classname.isVowel method.

Also you would need your loop be changed from

```
for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.length(); i++)
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
```

Also for comparison you should use as

```
 if (isVowel.isVowelValid(letter)) //or use ==
```

instead of

```
 if (isVowel.isVowelValid(letter) = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isVowelValid
isValidVowel
```

Typo alert. These are not the same.

Also this will be a compilation error after you correct the typo:

```
//                               v
if( isVowel.isValidVowel(letter) = true )
```

`=` is the assignment operator. You mean to use `==` which is for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You method as you defined it is called:

```
isValidVowel
```

The method that you are calling is:

```
isVowelValid
```

See the difference? The method name that you are invoking is not the same as the method name that you have defined.

Change your invocation to:

```
if (isVowel.isValidVowel(letter) == true)
```

And then it will work.

(Note that you need to use the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operation `=`, or you can drop the whole `== true` part altogether)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if(...)` in `VowelsA3` to

```
       if (isVowel.isValidVower(letter))
```

And not

```
      if (isVowel.isVowelValid(letter) = true)
```